# Change border color of input when it is filled in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
  const otpFilled = !input
    ? styles.underlineStyleBase
    : styles.underlineStyleHighLighted;

 <OtpInputs
          numberOfInputs={pinCount}
          defaultValue={input}
          handleChange={handleTextChange}
          inputStyles={styles.input}
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
          keyboardAppearance="dark"
          inputContainerStyles={[styles.underlineStyleBase, otpFilled]}
          focusStyles={styles.underlineStyleHighLighted}
          secureTextEntry={secureText}
          autofillFromClipboard={false}
          autoFocus={true}
          selectionColor={colors.brand_white}
          onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        />
```

**Styles**

```
   underlineStyleBase: {
      borderRadius: 12,
      height: 48,
      width: 48,
      borderColor: grey,
      borderWidth: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    underlineStyleHighLighted: {
      borderColor: 'white',
    },
```

I am trying to achieve the border color of TextInput box of react native when the input is filled it should be white and if the input is blank it should be grey

Comment: Don't you have `value` prop in your `<OtpInputs  ..../>` ? and I hope `handleTextChange` is changing the value of `input` state, is it ?

Comment: which package you are using ?